# Visual Studio Diff shows unwanted case differences

Tags: visual-studio, diff, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to compare two versions of a VBA file which are placed on a TFS. The Diff Tool shows several changes, but there actually are none.

[♪And they don't stop coming...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un5yg.png)

In fact, VS tries to beautify the code by changing it's case despite the fact that I turned the *Pretty Listing* feature off.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Q86.png)

[Well, I've disabled literally EVERYTHING here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCndu.png)

Note: VS does not change the files either on disk or TFS.
The question is how to make it stop. I can't find real changes when comparing files.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.4.6

Comment: Case change is a "real" change ^^

Comment: @Blanko well yeah, they could be but no one did those changes. And as I mentioned, the files remain unchanged so it is not a "real" change.

Comment: according to https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1135464-excel-vba-case-sensitive-or-not.html the case doesn't matter. If you use external difftools like winmerge or csdif, it's easy to ask them to ignore the case. Maybe it would be easier?

Comment: @B.Go Unfortunately I'm tied to VS because it is connected to our TFS. Thanks to that I can easily compare two versions of a file from the server.

Yes, the case doesn't matter and I don't need VS to fix it for me

Comment: It looks like the reason was the VBA editor. [Check here for more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676275/access-vba-changes-uppercase-lowercase-randomly)